# How to add Assets Catalog for iOS in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, info.plist

I am using `Xamarin Forms`. I was facing one weird issue from the past two days. First I have created App with assets catalog and not included a key for "CFBundleIconName". Then after just a few minutes, I got an error like

> A value for the Info.plist key 'CFBundleIconName' is missing in the bundle "xxx".

Then after I have tried with assets catalog and removed above key from  info.plist file. Then I got an error like

> Missing Asset Catalog - Your app is missing the asset catalog file

If I am removing below lines from a plist file then getting 120X120 icon file missing.

```
<key>XSAppIconAssets</key>
<string>Media.xcassets\AppIcons.appiconset</string>
<key>CFBundleIcons</key>
<dict>
    <key>CFBundlePrimaryIcon</key>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleIconName</key>
        <string>icon</string>
        <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
        <array>
            <string>icon-20@2x.png</string>
            <string>icon-20@3x.png</string>
            <string>icon-29@2x.png</string>
            <string>icon-29@3x.png</string>
            <string>icon-40@2x.png</string>
            <string>icon-40@3x.png</string>
            <string>icon-60@2x.png</string>
            <string>icon-60@3x.png</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Are the above lines are necessary to include in plist file? What other things are necessary to include in plist file.

And My project structure is :

[image]

What is wrong with my code? How can I add all files and assets?
Any idea?

Comment: Thank you everyone for answers and comments. There is nothing wrong with my code. I have just build IPA using Visual Studio for mac and it's uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

Delete all images and those lines from the info.plist.

Your Info.Plist should have the following lines:

```
<key>XSAppIconAssets</key>
<string>Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset</string>
<key>XSLaunchImageAssets</key>
<string>Assets.xcassets/LaunchImage.launchimage</string>
```

Add all the required icons to Asset Catalogs/Media

Comment: Which images should I Removed? And My folder name is Media.xcassets, so is this valid to replace it with Assets.xcassets?

Comment: You are using Windows, well, so replace Media.xcassets. Just delete,and redo the process, adding all the images to the Catalog. Don't you have access to the Media Catalog, with all the options?

Comment: Okay. Let me try one more time.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, But I have solved it by just moving my code from windows to Mac and generate new IPA in mac. Then it's working.